When is Fraïssé construction a colimit?
Let $\mathcal{M}_\text{eb}(\mathcal{L})$ be the category of $\mathcal{L}$-structures and $\mathcal{L}$-embeddings. Amalgamation property can be viewed as the existence of a cocone of the diagram $\mathcal{D}$: $\mathcal{A}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$, i.e. a natural transformation from the functor $\iota:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{M}_\text{eb}(\mathcal{L})$ sending everything to itself, to a constant functor $e:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{M}_\text{eb}(\mathcal{L})$ sending everything to some $e\in \mathcal{M}_\text{eb}(\mathcal{L})$.
The joint embedding property can also be viewed as the existence of a cocone of diagram $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{N}$.
Fraïssé construction says that for a countable language $\mathcal{L}$ and a certain collection of finitely generated $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathcal{K}$, if $\mathcal{K}$ has the joint embedding property, the amalgamation property, and is closed under taking finitely generated substructures, then there is a unique $\mathcal{K}$-saturated structure $\mathcal{U}$ up to isomorphism, which means that the set of finitely generated substructures of $\mathcal{U}$ is precisely $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is a cocone of the diagram consisting of elements in $\mathcal{K}$ and the $\mathcal{L}$-embeddings between those elements.
When is a Fraïssé construction a colimit, i.e. an initial object in the category of such cocones? For example, in the case of vector spaces, it is not initial.

"$\mathcal{U}$ is a cocone of the diagram consisting of elements of $\mathcal{K}$, which is up to isomorphism" doesn't make much sense. Which diagram, exactly? If you take the diagram to consist of all embeddings between all elements of $\mathcal{K}$, then $\mathcal{U}$ is not a cocone.

On the other hand, $\mathcal{U}$ is the colimit of the diagram consisting of all finitely generated substructures of $\mathcal{U}$ and all the inclusions between them. But this is nothing special about the Fraïssé limit: it's true about every structure.

Final comments: You've misspelled Fraïssé, and you've misstated Fraïssé's theorem: $\mathcal{K}$ should be a class of finite (or finitely generated) structures, and "every structure in $\mathcal{K}$ can be embedded in $\mathcal{U}$" is called "$\mathcal{K}$-universality". The key property of the Fraïssé limit, $\mathcal{K}$-saturation, is significantly stronger.

Final final thing: can you explain your reasoning why the Fraïssé limit is not a colimit in the case of vector spaces?

@AlexKruckman I revised the statements and I hope it is clearer now. The point of whether Fraïssé construction is a colimit is whether the morphism to other cocone of the same diagram is unique.

Again, your characterization of $\mathcal{K}$-saturation is not correct, and I repeat that $\mathcal{U}$ is not a cocone of the diagram consisting of all the embeddings between all elements of $\mathcal{K}$! I'll write an answer later trying to clarify all of this.

@AlexKruckman In the category of set, every set is the colimit of its subsets. But I think structure might not be the colimit of its finitely generated substructures, because substructures might not run over all the subsets, which leaves room for non-uniqueness of the morphism.

Every element is an element of some finitely generated substructure.

Fix a language $\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}\L$. We work in the category of $\L$-structures and $\L$-embeddings.
Let $\newcommand{\K}{\mathcal{K}}\K$ be a Fraïssé class: a class of finitely generated $\L$-structures which is countable up to isomorphism and satisfies the amalgamation property, the joint embedding property, and the hereditary property. Let $\newcommand{\U}{\mathcal{U}}\U$ be the Fraïssé limit of $\K$.
Then $\U$ can be characterized as the unique $\L$-structure up to isomorphism with the following properties:

$\U$ is countable.
$\mathrm{Age}(\U) = \K$, which means that the class of finitely generated substructures of $\U$ is exactly $\K$ (up to isomorphism).
If $A,B\in \K$ and $f\colon A\to \U$ and $g\colon A\to B$ are embeddings, then there exists an embedding $h\colon B\to \U$ such that $h\circ g = f$.

In your question, you provided the following attempted characterization of the Fraïssé limit:

The set of finitely generated substructures of $\U$ is precisely $\K$ and $\U$ is a cocone of the diagram consisting of elements in $\K$ and [all] the $\L$-embeddings between those elements.

Let's call this diagram $\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}\D$. I added the [all] to the description of $\D$ for clarity, because it seems to me that this is what you intended. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
These descriptions are not equivalent! For one thing, you omitted countability, which is essential to the uniqueness up to isomorphism. But also, in the definition of the Fraïssé limit, (2) and (3) imply the following:
For all $A,B\in \K$, for all $f\colon A\to \U$, for all $g\colon A\to B$, there exists $h\colon B\to \U$ such that $h\circ g = f$.
Whereas the statement that $\U$ is a cocone of $\D$ implies the following:
For all $A,B\in \K$, there exist $f\colon A\to \U$ and $h\colon B\to U$ such that for all $g \colon A\to B$, $h\circ g = f$.
Note the quantifier order is different.
Except in very trivial cases, I claim that $\D$ has no cocone whatsoever! For example, consider the case of the empty language, where $\K$ is the class of all finite sets. Suppose for contradiction that $M$ is a cocone of $\D$, witnessed by embeddings $f_A\colon A\to M$ for all $A\in \K$. Let $A = \{*\}$ be a set with one element, $B = \{0,1\}$ a set with two elements, and $g,h\colon A\to B$ defined by $g(*) = 0$ and $h(*) = 1$. Then since $g$ and $h$ are arrows in $\D$, we have $f_B\circ g = f_A = f_B\circ h$. Thus $f_B(0) = f_B(g(*)) = f_B(h(*)) = f_B(1)$, contradicting the fact that $f_B$ is injective.
The same argument works whenever there are objects $A,B\in \K$ such that there is more than one embedding $A\to B$.

Ok, so $\U$ is not even a cocone of $\D$, much less its colimit. In what other sense could a Fraïssé limit be a colimit?
Well, the standard construction of the Fraïssé limit goes by carefully building a chain of structures in $\K$ and embeddings: $$A_0\to A_1\to A_2\to \dots$$
and taking the "union", which is the (directed) colimit of this diagram. But this might be unsatisfying, because the chain is not canonically associated to $\K$.
You might be interested in work of Kubiś and Mašulović on Katětov functors. If the class $\K$ can be equipped with a Katětov functor, then we can build the Fraïssé limit as the colimit of a canonical chain obtained by iterating the functor.
Another approach is to view $\U$ as the (directed) colimit of the diagram consisting of all of its finitely generated substructures. Since the class of finitely generated substructures of $\U$ is exactly $\K$, we obtain $\U$ as a colimit of a diagram whose objects are $\K$ (up to isomorphism) - it's just that this diagram includes at most one arrow between any two objects, instead of all embeddings as in the diagram $\D$ above.
That sounds nice, but the universal property of the colimit does not actually encode the properties of the Fraïssé limit, as the following fact shows.
Proposition: Let $M$ be any $\L$-structure. Let $\D_M$ be the diagram consisting of all finitely generated substructures of $M$ and all inclusion maps between them (so there is an arrow $A\to B$ in the diagram if and only if $A\subseteq B\subseteq M$, and when this arrow exists, it is the inclusion). Then $M$ is the colimit of $\D_M$.
Proof: For each object $A$ in the diagram, let $i_A$ be the inclusion $A\to M$. If $f\colon A\to B$ is an arrow in the diagram, then $i_B\circ f = i_A$ simply because all three maps are inclusions into $M$. So $M$ is a cocone of $\D_M$.
Now suppose $N$ is a cocone of $\D_M$, witnessed by embeddings $j_A\colon A\to N$ for all $A$ in $\D_M$. We define $e\colon M\to N$. For $m\in M$, let $A = \langle m\rangle$ be substructure of $M$ generated by $m$. Since $A$ is finitely generated, it is an object in $\D_M$, and we define $e(m) = j_A(m)$. It is strightforward to check that this is an embedding and makes the appropriate diagram commute. For uniqueness, suppose $e'\colon M\to N$ is another embedding making the diagram commute. Then for all $m\in M$, again letting $A = \langle m\rangle$, we have $e'(m) = e'(i_A(m)) = j_A(m) = e(m)$, so $e = e'$.
